# Sympa install on CentOS/Fedora

Tags: sympa

Has anyone installed the Sympa mailing list software on Fedora or CentOS? I am not a huge fan of their instructions on sympa.org. I have installed the program and emails are working, but I can't seem to get the web site to work. Any help or links to a better install guide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On my debian site, I have to configure CGI (and fastCGI). Debian provide me a file /etc/apache2/conf.d/sympa with the redirection

```
ScriptAlias /wws /usr/lib/cgi-bin/sympa/wwsympa.fcgi
```

Then I can access to the webinterface by http://server/wws
I configure the virtualhost with

```
DirectoryIndex wws
```

And I can access directly to http://server/ and see the site.

Use FastCGI : it REALLY much faster than cgi !

Answer (score 0):

I think You can follow this steps:

http://marksallee.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/sympa-listserv-install-how-to-for-centos/

Before starting those steps, please read following url

http://www.sympa.org/manual/installing-sympa

Best wishes